# Matching an element in a list from a column of strings, if element found, return entire row

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

If there is a column that holds strings and if a single element matches from our list, Return entire row. For example we have a data frame:

```
index             x
0                apple, orange, strawberry
1                blueberry, pear, watermelon
2                apple, banana, strawberry
3                apple
4                strawberry

And we have our list,
a = [apple, strawberry]
# I am trying to return index 0,2,3 and 4. But currently I am only able to return index 3 and 4
new_DF = df[df['x'].isin(a)]
```

```
# This function is getting the user input for list 'a'. 
# This is for reference of what I am actually trying to do. 

def filter_Industries():
    num_of_industries = int(input('How many industries would you like to filter by?\n'))
    list_industries = []  
    i = 0
    for i in range(num_of_industries):
        industry = input("Enter the industry:\n")
        i += 1
        list_industries.append(industry)

    return list_industries

a = filter_Industries()
# This is where I am trying to match the elements from the user's list to the data set.
new_DF = df[df['x'].isin(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list `a` to `set`, split the column `x` and test if there's intersection between the set and the values in the row:

```py
a = {"apple", "strawberry"}  # <-- convert a to set

x = df.loc[
    df["x"].apply(lambda v: bool(a.intersection(map(str.strip, v.split(","))))), "index"
]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
0    0
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: index, dtype: int64
```